# How to launch Unity 3D App from a native iOS App

Tags: ios, ios7, unity-game-engine

I have an iOS project with me which was developed in Xcode 5. I also have a Unity 3D project developed in 4.3 free version. This Unity 3D project contains an animation video which I want to play. This project is already build for iOS. What I want is, I first launch my iOS App, then when I click on a button, this Unity 3D animation should play. From the Unity 3D, I should also be able to come back to the iOS App by clicking a Back button or something. To achieve this, I tried out the steps mentioned in the link below - http://alexanderwong.me/post/29949258838/building-a-ios-unity-uiview-uiviewcontroller - 
but it didn't help; a lot of link errors were generated. This link mentions about modifying a class named AppController. I didn't find such a class in my Unity 3D project, instead I saw a class named UnityAppController instead, hence I modified that.

Could someone guide me regarding how I can accomplish the above mentioned task. If any of you guys can provide me with some sample code that works, then it would be of great help. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you find a solution for that ?

Comment: This is a old old question but in case anyone else finds themselves here - you CAN bring the unity player inside your app (90-110Mb) but it seems to only run in full-screen on mobile devices. I'm currently working on getting SOME native ui to show up over the top, like navbars etc - no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 different applications: Your native app, and the Unity app, you can do the following:

Communicating with Other Apps:
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18

And you'll have to register a custom URL schema for the app, you want to open:
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50

Then, to open the app which has registered the custom URL schema you call the following, for instance:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mycustomurlschema://app"]];
```

To call this from your Unity app when you want to switch back to your native app, you have to follow these instructions in order to execute native code:
**Building Plugins for iOS:**
https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

If you want to, however, combine your native app and your Unity app into one single app please tell me if you find out how to do this. I searched the internet for a good solution, but the only solutions I could find were projects where Unity is permanently running in the background and draw some native views over the Unity-view which seems to be not a very good solution and quite cumbersome.